# Error when running gradle generated script running Kotlin Spring-Boot run

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

I have a newly generated spring-boot project with gradle as build tool and Kotlin as a language.
I put in the build.gradle.kts an application plugin and I configured it setting the main class.
Then I run:

```
gradle build installDist
```

as a result I got build/install/demo/bin and build/install/demo/lib folders.
The bin folder contains a script that runs my spring boot app.
Unfortunatelly when I run it I got an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt
```

My build.gradle.kts looks like this:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    application
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.3.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
```

I made sure the the class name and the package name are correct, yet I get this error while running : `./build/install/demo/bin/demo`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the `application` field and add the following `jar` field:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt'
    }
}
```